# Piping from Python's ftplib without blocking

Tags: python, ftp, stream, pipe, ftplib

Ideally what I'd like to do is replicate this bash pipeline in python (I'm using `cut` here to represent some arbitrary transformation of the data. I actually want to use `pandas` to do this):

```
curl ftp://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/database/refFlat.txt.gz | gunzip | cut -f 1,2,4
```

I can write the following code in python, which achieves the same goal

```
# Download the zip file into memory
file = io.BytesIO()
ftp = ftplib.FTP('hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu')
ftp.retrbinary(f'RETR goldenPath/{args.reference}/database/refFlat.txt.gz', file.write)

# Unzip the gzip file
table = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=file)

# Read into pandas
df = pd.read_csv(table)
```

However, the `ftp.retrbinary()` call blocks, and waits for the whole download. What I want is to have one long binary stream, with the FTP file as the source, with a `gunzip` as a filter, and with `pd.read_csv()` as a sink, all simultaneously processing data, as in my bash pipeline. Is there a way to stop `retrbinary()` from blocking?

I realise this may be impossible because python can't use more than one thread. Is this true? If so, can I use `multiprocessing` or `async` or some other language feature to achieve this simultaneous pipeline

*edit: changed `storbinary` to `retrbinary`, this was a typo and the problem still stands*

Comment: Python can totally use multiple threads. You're thinking of the GIL, which is different.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download the file directly to the `GZipFile`:

```
gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile()
ftp.retrbinary(f'RETR goldenPath/{args.reference}/database/refFlat.txt.gz', gzipfile.write)
```